# Mysql database with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database

I backed up the mysql database from my windows wamp and i copied the the data to ubuntu mysql. I am given the database only and not the table. any help in how to be able to get the table back.

Answer (score 2):

Moving a MySQL database involves "*exporting*" it and then "*importing*" it, **not** copying it. You have identified that you have "*phpmyadmin*" installed. On your Windows computer use it to export your database. Copy the resulting file to your Ubuntu computer and use "*phpmyadmin*" on your Ubuntu computer, in this case, to import it.

Alternatively use: [mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)